# When should one consider using Azure's site-to-site connectivity?

Tags: azure

Can you please explain what is Azure's site-to-site connectivity feature? How is it different from Point-to-Site connectivity?

I could not understand the difference from Azure's official documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Site to Site is making a connection between your local, on premises network and a Virtual Network in Windows Azure.  For example, if you spin up a few Virtual Machines in Windows Azure that host SQL Servers, then any of the machines in your local network can access them.  Most often this is referred to as "extending your data center".  This is best used when you want to host one more Virtual Machines in Windows Azure and have bi-directional communication between those machines and machines within your own local network.

The Point-to-site is connection between a single machine and the Virtual Network in Windows Azure.  An example might be that you have a Virtual Machines in Windows Azure and you want a single machine on your local network, or maybe even an Operations person's laptop, to have access to those cloud based machines.  I've heard of people doing this in their development and testing environment for troubleshooting and maintenance tasks.  In addition I've heard it used for laptops that are generally outside of the corporate firewall or remote workers that need access to the servers in Windows Azure.  At this time (Oct 2013) the Point to Site feature is in preview.

I'm not sure if you saw the section of Secure Connection Types in the documentation, but check out this [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx).

Comment: Is there any way to get bidirectional communication with a Point 2 Site VPN to Azure? I would like a VS test controller on my computer and agents on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a point to what MikeWo said in earlier answer, for your point to site implementation you need to generate a certificate and install it in each single machine you would like to use the point to site connection, however for site to site VPN, it is using pre-shared key on the router so all the users on a corporate network are able to connect to Azure network. Currently azure site to site VPN is using AES 256 bit encryption algorithm.

Based on my experience, point to site VPN is slower than site to site connection in terms of speed and data exchange.